# rm -r /media/externalHD --> can't boot without external HD anymore

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, ls, rm

My external HD was mounted in /media/user/TRANSFER.
By mistake I typed

```
sudo rm -r /media/theo/TRANSFER
```

There was an error because the device was occupied and fortunately, I haven't lost my data.

But now, I'm facing the problem, that I can only boot, if my external HD is plugged in and it has a strange color scheme in the terminal: output of `ls -l /media/theo`

[image: output].

Here is the entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=43D0-11ED  /media/theo/TRANSFER    vfat    rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,umask=0030   2
```

What can I do to fix the error?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You may remove that entry in the fstab (probably). There could be other thing tough, like having installed the bootloader (Grub) in the wrong location or other situations.

Comment: Removing the entry in fstab and reformatting the HD did fix it.
As it isn't really a solution and I don't know what happened, I won't mark it as fixed.